# ContextMenu binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to call ContextMenu on left mouse click on button if number of menu items is greater than 1. This is my XAML:

```
<Button Content="Items" Click="Button_Click">
<Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    </ContextMenu>
</Button.ContextMenu></Button>
```

And this is code behind:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button senderButton = sender as Button;
        if (senderButton == null) return;
        var items = senderButton.ContextMenu.Items;
        if (items.Count < 2) return;
        senderButton.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = senderButton;
        senderButton.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

The problem is that items. Count is always equals to 0 even though when I remove `if (items.Count < 2) return;` line it show items well

Comment: Are you sure that *there are* actually any item inside context menu? Where did you bind it to a collection of items.

Comment: Did you also set the DataContext of the container of Button?